# Notification count on unread private message replies

Tags: mysql, database-design, join, count

I have a Private messaging system using PHP and mySQL with notification.

The database table has following fields(not all listed) --- message_tbl:

```
MessageID
senderUserID
RecUserID
Message
Subject
DateTime
Status - whether read or not i.e 0/1
```

All replies are stored in a second table, since each message creates a thread. A thread exist within the parent message, so everytime a parent message is loaded all its replies also are loaded with it.
The second table looks a bit like this: - replies_tbl

```
messageID - FK
senderUserID
rstatus - how should i use this?
Mesage
DateTime
```

I need to show count of all the unread messages.
At the moment i run a sql count function  to get total unread messages from the message_tbl where status is 0 and userid equal to RecUserID, the easy part.

But i have a small issue is how to get count for the replies table? Can the database design be improved?

thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, a reply is, itself, a message, so why is it going into a separate table. What happens with a reply to a reply? It would seem you would have a null FK at that point.

My first thought is:

- Add ParentID column to Messages table
- Set ParentID to 0 for root messages
- Set ParentID to the MessagesID if it's a reply

With that structure, you could easily track replies to replies and the thread could continue as deep as you wanted it to ...

Just my thoughts, though ...

Comment: yes your indeed correct, but so in this case how would I get all the replies for a  selected message?

Comment: If you have the message id (say stored in the variable `$message_id`): `SELECT * WHERE parentID = '$message_id'`

Comment: d'oh that makes sense. another question say if wanted to display messages not replies in the inbox, would you `select subject from messagetbl where RecUserID = $userid AND parentID =0` am i correct?